# Difference between ⊨ and ⊢

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I know there are multiple questions about this, but I still dont get it.
$⊢$ is the syntactic consequence. Syntactic in this case would mean that we only care about the form of the sentence and not the meaning.

While $⊨$ is called semantic consequence. Now my question is, how is this a **semantic** consequence if I've read on multiple books, and it's really stressed out, that we don't have to take in consideration the meaning of the sentence to find a valuation for it but only have to care about the logical form of the sentence? That should be what distinguishes logical consequence from material consequence no?.

The explenation I always find for $A, B⊨C$ is roughly if its impossible (in any world) for $A$ and $B$ to be true and $C$ to be false.
While for $A, B⊢C$ if you can derive C with a proof system from A and B.
But isn't that exactly what I have to do to show that $A, B⊨C$?

What's "semantic" about $⊨$?

I know that in prepositional and predicate logic they are equivalent  (soundness and completeness) and that's why I guess It's confusing but I don't really really understand the difference.
Could you please explain me without mentioning models and structures since I've never studied model theory? And I only know basic PL and QL?

Comment: "Without mentioning models and structures" - well, this is your issue. $\models$ is *defined* in terms of models, and this is the sense in which it is semantic.

Comment: @Alex Kruckman so in order to understand It i have to learn model theory?

Comment: No, but you have to understand what a model is. If you're struggling with the notion of a model, then start there before trying to grasp notions like $\vDash$ that depend on this notion.

Comment: @lemontree is model = interpretation = q-valuation?

Comment: This is best asked in a new question.